# Define a pre-processor variable for all the files in make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, c-preprocessor

I have a number of `.c` and `.h` files with some parts of the code disabled by putting the code block in pre-processor directives e.g.

```
#ifdef FOOBAR
// some code that can be compiled if needed by defining FOOBAR in pre-processor.
#endif
```

No I need to define `FOOBAR` such that its defined for every file that is compiled by gcc using `make`.

Is there a way to do this with some option to make or `Makefile` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the compiler option `-DFOOBAR` to the make variable `CFLAGS`

Comment: It should be noted that this is not just a gcc-ism but part of the POSIX standard for C compiler invocation.

Comment: Thanks...although I had a few folders each with its own `Makefile` and I had to add this `CFLAGS=...` to each one of them, it worked. I wished there was such a thing while calling make. Like e.g. `make -flags -DFOOBAR` or something similar. But thanks for then answer.

Comment: @mtahmed, there is. Just put the variable definitions on the command line of make, `make CFLAGS='-O3 -march=native -DFOOBAR'`

Comment: @JensGustedt, Can the variable have a value?

Comment: @JensGustedt, Found it (for gcc).  `-D'macro=definition'`. It does not seem to properly work without the outer single quotations. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).

Comment: It took me a while to figure out, that I can't just do `FOOBAR=1 make`.